# Is there a more eloquent way of comparing three or more values other than long conditionals

Tags: javascript, compare, logic, conditional-statements

What is the cleanest/ most eloquent way of comparing more than two values against one another ? In the example below I am testing lengths of three strings.

```
function findMinLengthOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {

  var x = word1.length;
  var y = word2.length;
  var z = word3.length;

 if(x < y && x < z)
    return x;
  else if( y < x && y < z)
    return y;
  else 
    return z;
```

Comment: `Math.min(x, y, z)`?

Comment: @Xufox. Wow, boy do I feel dumb. Learn a new method every day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) for that.

```
function findMinLengthOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  var x = word1.length;
  var y = word2.length;
  var z = word3.length;

  return Math.min(x, y, z);
}
```

Or just

```
Math.min(word1.length, word2.length, word3.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend the behavior of the function to compare more than 3 numbers at once, you can use the `arguments` keyword, convert into an array and use the spread operator to distribute the values into the `Math.min` function. Like this.

```
function minNum(){
  return Math.min(...Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
}

console.log(minNum(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findMinLengthOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
    return Math.min(word1.length, word2.length, word3.length);
}
var output = findMinLengthOfThreeWords('a', 'be', 'see');
console.log(output); // --> 1
```